# Why can't I install the libraries from VCPKG into my Ubuntu Linux when trying to install compatible libraries?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, vcpkg

I am using the VCPKG on my VSCode program using Ubuntu, but I don't know how to install the libraries that I need.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  string title = "Basic Mathematics Calculator";
  cout << title;
  int x, y;
  cout << "Input a number: ";
  cin >> x;
  cout << "Input another number: ";
  cin >> y;
  int sum = x + y;
  cout << "Your number is: " << sum << "\n";
  cout << "Thank you for using the " << title << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

As you can see, I am including the iostream and string 'libraries' but they don't exist. I have been trying to install them but I keep getting an error which says:

```
error: building bzip2:x64-linux failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
```

I have tried using the line `./vcpkg/vcpkg install zstr`
but I keep getting this message or similar:

```
error: building bzip2:x64-linux failed with: BUILD_FAILED
Please ensure you're using the latest port files with `git pull` and `vcpkg update`.
```

Comment: `iostream` and `string` are both part of the C++ standard library.  You shouldn't need to install anything extra to use them (other than a C++ compiler).  Have you installed the `g++` package from the Ubuntu repo (i.e. `apt install g++`)?

Comment: I already have but apparently `#include <iostream>` and `#include <string>` don't work. The quick fix says to add it in the include path but I don't have a folder of the two.